# How to use ember sass in ember addon and correctly implement it into ember project

Tags: ember.js, sass, ember-addon

The following problem needs to be solved: I try to create a component within an ember addon, that's using sass. Within my addon I don't want to compile that scss files, that should be done within my project using ember-cli-sass and ember-css-modules-sass. The component I'm creating in my addon is also using sass modules, but I didn't install the ember packages for this, because I do that in my project.

I run into the problem, that when I try to serve my ember application from my project directory, I get the error that within my addon an imported scss file is unreadable or not there.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you please share the related code snippets? What you are trying to do is supported and done by popular addons like [Ember Bootstrap](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/).

Comment: Let me ask different: what would be the correct way to follow?

Comment: It should be fine if you put the `*.scss` files in `app/styles` folder of your addon. It's merged with `app/styles` of your app on build time. This allows you to import it as if the file were part of the app. You must ensure that you don't have name conflicts. A convention to do so is using a folder with the name of the addon.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Sass files to `/app/styles/`, not `/addon/styles`. This way they will be merged with the host app.